# Java Streams and Collectors, how to group by fields in nested collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class like the one below:

```
public class Company {
    private List<Team> teams;
}

public class Team {
    String name;
}
```

I have a list of Compony objects like this:

```
List<Company> companies = ...
```

Teams can belong to and appear in the list of more than one company.

I am looking to use Java streams to group the companies into a map, with team name as the map key. The value of each map entry is a list of companies that the team belongs to. Like this.

```
Map<String, List<Company>> companiesGroupedByTeam;
```

So the same company may appear in lists for different teams.

Does anyone know how to use java streams to do this grouping? Struggling to do the group by part.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to create a stream from the company collection, then to do a flat map to a list of teams names, but struggling how to then collect that into a map of company lists with the team name as the key.

Comment: So, show us what have you done first. Then only we can help you.

Comment: I don't have anything working that I can show you. That's why I am asking for help. If that's not enough for you then I'll just go and try somewhere else then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like:

```
Map<String, List<Company>> collect = companies.stream()
            .flatMap(c -> c.getTeams().stream()
                     .map(t -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(t.getName(), c)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                         Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```